# Interpretation of supercript and subscript on sigma symbol

Tags: discrete-mathematics, notation

Given Σ<sub>1</sub> = {a, b}, and Σ<sub>2</sub> = {1, 2, 3}

What does Σ<sup>3</sup><sub>1</sub> or Σ<sup>3</sup><sub>2</sub> mean? Note that the 1 and 2 are meant to appear as subscripts of Σ, I wasn't sure how to do that here on stack exchange.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: They are only names of two sets... Set $\Sigma_1 = \{ a,b \}$ is the set with $a$ and $b$ as elements.

Comment: Learn [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to display mathematical formulae correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The superscripts indicate power sets. For any set $S$, the notation $S^n$ means the set of ordered $n$-tuples of elements of $S$. For example, $\Sigma_1^2=\{(a,a), (a,b),(b,a),(b,b)\}$ and $\Sigma_2^3$ is a 27-element set comprising elements that are triples such as $(1,1,1)$, $(1,1,2)$, ... , $(3,3,3)$.